# Yii condition <IS NULL>

Tags: php, activerecord, yii, conditional-statements, criteria

How to find row by column with null value?

It doesn't work:

```
$criteria->condition = '`seller_id` IS NULL';
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
$criteria->addCondition('seller_id IS NULL');
$data= MODEL::model()->find($criteria);
```

**tried this?** **seller_id** is the mapped column name in **Yii**, it may not be same as the actual column name in your database.

Comment: tnx, it works. But I am confused. seller_id in model is seller_id in table. Names are the same! WTF?

Comment: claim down... if it works, its fine. normally, the database column names are mapped exactly and correctly. glad it helps.

Comment: Sorry, meant to post comment, not answer.

I actually [filed a bug][1] on this long ago. Qiang said he wouldn't fix it. I think it's a flaw. Another reason for me to fork the code!


  [1]: http://code.google.com/p/yii/issues/detail?id=837&can=1&q=reporter:jerryablan@gmail.com&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Milestone%20Owner%20Stars%20Summary

Comment: @The Keeper of the Cheese Thanks you for the info