# Using condition or in cdbcriteria

Tags: php, yii

Currently my code looks like that

```
    $criteria = new CDbCriteria();
    $criteria->compare('visible', 1);
    $criteria->compare('branch_id', $this->id);
```

What I want is to do something like that

```
`branch_id`='$this->id' OR `branch_id` is NULL
```

How to do it with `compare` function?

Answer (score 4):

[Yii condition <IS NULL>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5349788/yii-condition-is-null)

So maybe you'd like to do

```
$idCrit = new CDbCriteria();
$idCrit->compare('branch_id', $this->id);
$idCrit->addCondition('branch_id is NULL', 'OR');

$criteria->mergeWith($idCrit);
```

Where `$criteria` holds all the other stuff?

Some further reading;

- http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCriteria#addCondition-detail
- http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCriteria#mergeWith-detail

(Look specifically at the `$operator` argument.)

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
$criteria->compare('field', array(NULL));
```

Answer (score 0):

use this:
**$criteria->compare('branch_id', array($this->id, null));**

as you can see in code:
https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/1.1.14/framework/db/schema/CDbCriteria.php#L414

"If the value is an array, the comparison is done by exact match of any of the value in the array."